# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream Console

Tags: php, ajax, download, zip, console.log

I have a file management system I'm building where only zip files are allowed. I dont want anyone to see where the file is stored on the server so I'm using an ajax call to a php file that executes the following:

```
if (!empty($find_url)) {
    foreach ($find_url as $file) {
        $dl =  urldecode($file->file_url);
    }
    $file_headers = @get_headers($dl);
    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
        $exists = false;
    } else {

        $exists = true;
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header('Location: '.$dl);

    }
}
```

The file downloads fine but it pumps out a console message pointing out the file location:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: 
"http://www.exmple.co.uk/someplace/filename.zip".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be normal on chrome when we try to download any file directly by entering its url in the browser. Tried downloading Chrome, Firefox & GitHub for windows and they all behaved the same way on chrome.

While giving a download link you can fix the same by adding download attribute inside  tag.

```
<a href="http://www.exmple.co.uk/someplace/filename.zip" download>Download File</a>
```

Comment: Yeah I've looked into the HTML5 download attribute. But I'm looking for a better browser compatible option really. I suppose I should have also mentioned that the way in which it sources the zip file location is done through an encrypted URL via AJAX/PHP. Probably not the best description of the process. sorry.